# Is this a better formulation of the Turing test?

Tags: ai-design, agi, turing-test, artificial-consciousness

Would the Turing test be better formulated by assessing whether the creator (as opposed to a third party) was able to tell the difference between their program and a human?

A magician, through the use of misdirection and slight of hand, could make an audience believe they are witnessing true magic, however the magician would only be able to make themselves believe if in fact the magic was real.

Would formulating the Turing test as such put a greater focus on creating “real” AI as opposed to the illusion of AI?

Answer (score 1):

For the purpose of having AI on par with humans and releasing it to the market is not that relevant that the creator, a single person, can still not be fooled.

Moreover this would create a conflict of interests, as the creator may pretend to be fooled.

In conclusion: no.